Vercel deployment failed,Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/vercel/path0/packages/nextjs/.next/export-detail.json'
When I used the @web3-storage/w3up-client library, there was no problem running it locally. When deployed to vercel, deployment failed.
Error message
Some library version:
"vercel": "^32.4.1"
"next": "^14.0.4"
"@web3-storage/w3up-client": "^14.1.1"
Code show as below:
import { CarReader } from "@ipld/car";
import { importDAG } from "@ucanto/core/delegation";
import { Signer } from "@ucanto/principal/ed25519";
import { Client, create } from "@web3-storage/w3up-client";
import { StoreMemory } from "@web3-storage/w3up-client/stores/memory";
import type { Block } from "@web3-storage/w3up-client/types";

async function initW3Client() {
const principal = Signer.parse(process.env.KEY as string);
const store = new StoreMemory();
const w3Client = await create({ principal, store });
const proof = await parseProof(process.env.PROOF as string);
const space = await w3Client.addSpace(proof);
await w3Client.setCurrentSpace(space.did());

return w3Client;
}

async function parseProof(data: string) {
const blocks = [];
const reader = await CarReader.fromBytes(Buffer.from(data, "base64"));
for await (const block of reader.blocks()) {
blocks.push(block as Block);
}

return importDAG(blocks);
}

When I delete the above code, vercel is deployed successfully. I don't know what is wrong with the above code.Can anyone help solve this problem?

I solved my problem by esbuild-plugin-w3up-client-wasm-import plugin
